# function that returns a table sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS MinCarAltezza;
 DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION MinCarAltezza(altezza INT) 
    RETURNS SchedaTab TABLE(
        Nome varchar(64),
        Cognome varchar(64),
        ID_Scheda int(10),
        Sequenza int(2),
        nSerie int(2),
        nRipetizioni int(2),
        Carico_Minimo decimal(4,1),
        Esercizio varchar(30),
        PRIMARY KEY(Nome,Cognome,Esercizio)
    ) 
    AS BEGIN
    INSERT SchedaTab
    SELECT DISTINCT U.Nome,U.Cognome,P.ID_Scheda,P.Sequenza,P.nSerie, 
            P.nRipetizioni,MIN(P.Carico),P.Esercizio
    FROM utente AS U, scheda AS S, programma AS P
    WHERE U.CF=S.ID_Utente AND S.ID_Scheda=P.ID_Scheda AND U.Altezza>altezza 
        AND P.Carico<>0 
        AND S.ID_Ist NOT IN(SELECT CF FROM istruttore WHERE Stipendio>500)
    GROUP BY U.Nome,U.Cognome,S.ID_Scheda

    RETURN   
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

that gives me an error in the line 4 where I declare the return type TABLE.
Is there something I'm missing?

That's the db if someone needs it: http://pastebin.com/DWYqVBpa

thank you

Comment: Make sure to include the exact text of the error given.  You can do add information to your question by clicking the `edit` link below the question (directly above these comments).  Do not post an image of this, just copy/paste the error text and include it in your question.  And do not put this information in comments - this belongs in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL there is no "table" data type, hence the error message. As MySQL documentation on [stored functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) says, return value can be

> Any valid MySQL [data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html)

Therefore, a stored function cannot return with a table. I would change the function into a stored procedure and

- have a select statement at the end of the procedure (MySQL return the result of the last select)
- or create a temporary table with the data and return the name of the temporary table in an out parameter